# PHP curl Zendesk to update ticket with subject and description

Tags: php, curl, zendesk

I want to update zendesk ticket by php curl method i want to update subject and description field. OR Is there anything We can have our own ticket id and pass it while creating ticket.

I was using following code to update ticket.

```
$create = json_encode(array('ticket' => array('subject' => $arr['z_subject'], 'description' => $arr['z_description'], 'requester' => array('name' => $arr['z_name'], 'email' => $arr['z_requester'],'custom_fields' => $custom_fields))), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

//new ticket
$data = curlWrap("/tickets.json", $create, "POST");

$ticket_id = $data->ticket->id;

$arr['z_description'] = $arr['z_description'] . " " . $ticket_id;
$arr['z_subject'] = $arr['z_subject'] . " " . $ticket_id;

print_r($arr);
echo "<br /><br />";

$create = json_encode(array('ticket' => array('subject' => $arr['z_subject'], 'description' => $arr['z_description'])));
$ticketid="/tickets/" . $ticket_id . ".json";

print $ticketid ."<br />";
//updating ticket
$data = curlWrap($ticketid, $create, "PUT");
var_dump($data);

function curlWrap($url, $json, $action)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ZDURL.$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, ZDUSER."/token:".ZDAPIKEY);

    switch($action){
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
            break;
        case "GET":
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $decoded = json_decode($output);
    return $decoded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here, [Zendesk Core API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/tickets#updating-tickets) the subject is nothing but the first comment you have posted, so, you can't change the subject. But you can do it for description just doing as mentioned on your question.

If this may help, whenever you create a ticket you receive a postback message containing the id and some more information as you can see here [Creating tickets](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/tickets#example-response).